# LEFT JOIN & SUBQUERY with empty columns / null as result

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I am trying to join two tables. A user table (including user id, username, email, password, etc.) and a table of logins, which contains a user id and a timestamp. As result I want an overview of all users with their last logins (only the most recent login of each user). If a user has never logged in the result for the time should be null.

So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    user.id, 
    user.username, 
    DATE_FORMAT(user_login.time, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%i") 
FROM 
    user 
LEFT JOIN 
    user_login 
ON 
    (user.id=user_login.user_id) 
WHERE 
    user_login.id=(
        SELECT 
            id 
        FROM 
            user_login 
        WHERE 
            user_id=user.id 
        ORDER BY 
            id DESC 
        LIMIT 1);
```

It delivers as result users with their most recent login, but only users which have at least one login, so at least one dataset in the user_login table. For each user who didn't ever login I want to get just null as result.

I already found a solution, but I use "1=1" as WHERE-clause in it, which seems really unprofessional to me. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    user.id, 
    user.username, 
    DATE_FORMAT(user_login.time, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%i") 
FROM 
    user 
LEFT JOIN 
    user_login 
ON 
    (user.id=user_login.user_id) 
WHERE 
    (user_login.id=(
        SELECT 
            id 
        FROM 
            user_login 
        WHERE 
            user_id=user.id 
        ORDER BY 
            id DESC 
        LIMIT 1) 
    OR 1=1) 
GROUP BY 
    user.id;
```

Does anyone have a better solution for this problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: A better solution would be to delete the complete `WHERE` clause. For users who did not login, the values from the table `user_login` will be `NULL`.

Comment: Which leave the question what you are trying todo with that `WHERE`calsue in the first place ...

Comment: @Luuk the where clause in this case is used to obtain the highest login id, probably the last time a user logged in (there can be multiple belonging to a user)

Comment: @Remy: I would use `MAX(user_login.time)` for that....

Comment: @Luuk Thanks! That's what I searched for! :) The only strange thing is, when I add an "ORDER BY user_login.time DESC" it shows me logins from december before logins from this month. But for now this is not important.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest window functions:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, 
       DATE_FORMAT(ul.time, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') 
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ul.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time DESC) as seqnum
      FROM user_login ul
     ) ul
     ON u.id = ul.user_id AND seqnum = 1;
```